# Wie kann ich meine Rechtschreibung verbessern?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

Ich versuche den Satz

> The economist Ludwig von Mises in his book Theory of Money and Credit introduced the idea of that people act in accordance with *ordinally* ranked preferences

auf Deutsch zu übersetzen. Ich bevorzuge keine Wörter griechischen/lateinischen Ursprungs zu verwenden (also z.B. *Vorliebe* statt *Präferenz*).

Mein Versuch:

> Der Wirtschafter Ludwig von Mises in Ihrem Buch Theory of Money and Credit führen die Idee ein, dass Leute handeln im Abkommen mit ordinal rangieren Vorlieben.

Comment: Ich verstehe die Frage nicht. Reine Übersetzungs-Anfragen sind off-topic

Comment: Der Ökonom Ludwig von Mises führt in seinem Buch 'Theory of Money and Credit' die Idee ein, das Leute gemäß numerisch gewichteter Präferenzen handeln.

Comment: @planetmaker Are you sure that this logically entails that the preferenze uses ORDINAL NUMBERS?. This is absolutally important to this.

Comment: No, I am absolutely not sure. And I find that indeed strange

Comment: Hi Henry, you may ask questions in English. Your German version was -no offence- very hard to understand. I took the liberty to edit in my guess of what you were trying to say.

Comment: Additionally, _Rechtschreibung_ means orthography, but I doubt it's what your looking for. Can you find a more fitting title for your question?

Comment: @infinitezero Gramatic I guess. Aber I mean Germanic terms over the Greco-Latin Words that were incorporated in German as in prettry much every European Language

Comment: @Henry bevorzugen is the correct word for _prefer_. _Vorleben_ is something else, it means to live by example.

Comment: Scientific terminology like "ordinally ranked preferences" is difficult to translate unless you have specific experience with this topic. According to a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Theory_of_Money_and_Credit), which links to an English full-text version, the German original title is *"Theorie des Geldes und der Umlaufsmittel"*. The [German version](https://www.mises.at/static/literatur/Buch/mises-theorie-des-geldes-und-der-umlaufsmittel-auflage2.pdf) is available as a PDF. Maybe you should compare English and German versions to find the terminology in German.

Comment: @Bodo The only thing that I was able to get is the term Ordnungsrang with my limited knowledge of German. Chapter 2 by the way.

Comment: @Henry: if you want to avoid "greco-latin words" then you should replace the latin "Idee" with the germanic "Einfall". Also is "ordinal" of latin origin. In general, though: the last time an organized effort to remove "greco-latin words" was made we ended with the "Vier-Topf-Vier-Bumms-Zerknalltreibling" - and then the Allies came and demolished everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Der Wirtschaftswissenschaftler Ludwig von Mises führt in seinem Buch *Theory of Money and Credit* die Idee ein, dass Menschen gemäß sortierter Vorlieben handeln.

Rechtschreibung ist das geringste der Probleme; Satzbau und Terminologie sind m.E. hier die Knackpunkte.

In der Statistik unterscheidet man verschiedene Skalen, anhand derer man Merkmale beschreibt.

Die schwächste Unterscheidung ist die Nominalskala. So könnte man fragen "Was ist Ihr Lieblingstier?" und als Antwort "Katze, Hund, Wellensittich, ..." - also qualitative Nomen erhalten, die keine inhärente Ordnung aufweisen.

Eine Ordinalskala dagegen weist eine Ordnung auf, etwa Schulnoten in der Grundschule, wie "sehr gut, gut, befriedigend, ausreichend, mangelhaft" und "ungenügend", die zwar oft auf Zahlen abgebildet werden (1-6), aber mathematische Operationen auf diesen Zahlen sind nicht sinnvoll. Der Unterschied zw. sehr gut und gut muss nicht so groß sein, wie der zwischen gut und befriedigend oder ein ausreichend ist nicht doppelt so schlecht wie ein gut.

Aber die Reihenfolge der Bewertungen ist fixiert.

Exkurs:

Bei der Intervallskala hat man es mit normierten Abständen zu tun, etwa bei °C. Der Temperaturabstand zw. 10 und 20°C ist der gleiche wie zw. 80 und 90°C. Der Nullpunkt kann aber ein willkürlicher sein.

Bei der Verhältnisskala gibt es auch einen begründeten Nullpunkt, etwa die Kelvinskala, die Prozent Wählerstimmen, die eine Partei bekommen hat, die Körpergröße in cm.

Bei der Absolutskala ist die Maßeinheit auch noch natürlich gegeben. Die cm der Körpergröße sind es nicht, da die Längeneinheit eine willkürliche ist. Die Anzahl der Haare auf dem Kopf dagegen ist abzählbar und daher absolut bestimmt (wenn auch keine übliche Maßeinheit). Die Zahl der Kinder einer Familie wäre ein besseres Beispiel. Misst man die Summe des Gewichts der Kinder in Kilogramm wäre es wiederum nur eine Verhältnisskala.

Comment: Der Wirtschaftswissenschaftler Ludwig von Mises führt in seinem Buch „Theorie der Geld und der Umlaufsmittel“ die Idee ein, dass Menschen gemäß einer Ordinalskala des Bevorzugungen handeln. Denn die Ordinalskala muss DEUTLICH beinhalten sein.

Comment: @Henry: Und was bedeutet Deiner Ansicht nach "Ordinalskala"? Und was ist "des Bevorzugungen"? Des Bevorzugten? Des Bevorzugenden? Verstehe ich nicht. Und was heißt "muss DEUTLICH beinhalten sein"? Beinhaltet sein? Was möchtest Du sagen?

Answer (score -2):

*Diese Antwort ist zu lang*. Fragesteller sollte wenigstens bis zum fette gedruckten Absatz lesen.

> Der Wirtschafter Ludwig von Mises in Ihrem Buch Theory of Money and Credit führen die Idee ein

Der Numerus des Verbs ist Singular und müsste dementsprechend gebeugt werden. Das Verb ist ein schwaches Verb, wird also regulär gebeugt.

Das Wort, welches hier das Subjekt darstellt, gibt es entweder nicht oder es ist sehr selten. Ein "economist" ist ein *Wissenschaftler* und wird dementsprechend bezeichnet.

> dass Leute handeln im Abkommen

Relativsätze wie dieser werden in Verbletztstellung aufgebaut, so dass Subjekt und infinites Verb die Paramater einschließen. Anders als hier kommt das Hauptverb des Nebensatzes oft von einem Hilfsverb. Das mag verwirrend sein, denn das Hilfsverb in Hauptsätzen geht zumeist als Kopf einer Verbalphrase voran. Das nötige Sprachgefühl dafür ist abhängig von weiteren Variablen, sowie die Parameter und Argumente (?) des Prädikatsatzes ebenso von verbhaften Partizipien, Verbalabstrakta usw. wie von definitiv sachlichen Objekten eben auch gebildet werden. Markanter Weise ist die Verbletztstellung jedoch die Zitatform, so dass zB. "? Wissen schaffen" als feste lexikalische Einheit verstanden werden könnte, die dem Wort "Wissenschaft" zugrunde liegt.

So dürfte es sich auch mit "im Abkommen handeln" verhalten, nicht zu verwechseln mit "Handelsabkommen". Damit verhält es sich anders als der eglische Orginaltext, an dessen Ende quasi ein zitierfähiger Absatz steht.

Die Kritik daran ist vielleicht verfrüht, falls das gewählte Verb gar nicht zu dem Rest der Übersetzung passt. Fraglich bleibt wie der Schluss zu Übersetzen ist. **Zuerst sollte man verstehen, was man da überhaupt übersetzen will.**

> people act in accordance with *ordinally* ranked preferences

Dazu wäre die Quelle der Aussage durchaus hilfreich. Ohne weiteres erscheint die Aussage nur redundant, weil Rang und Ordnung häufig synonym sind. Problematisch ist immerhin, dass "order" eine Polysemy aufweist, die den entsprechenden Wörtern im Deutschen fehlt. *Ordinal* zählt zum mathematischen Jargon und bezeichnet meines Wissens ausschließlich die Ordinalszahlen. Das entsprechende Adverb wurde vielleicht von *ordinär* verdrängt, das offensichtlich französisch ist. Es handelt sich gewissermaßen um verschiedene Sprachstufen und entgegengesetzte Register (technisches vs. umgangssprachlich absichtlich unpräzise Ausdrucksweise). *Ordentlich* steht nunmehr in ererbten Fügungen, ist darüber hinaus wiederum umgangssprachlich als *gut, sauber* usw. zu verstehen. Ebenso gilt *Ordnung* einerseits als Rechtsgrundlage, zu Deutsch *Satzung, Statut, Regeln*, so wie ein *Orden* eine nach festen Regeln zusammenlebende Gemeinschaft ist. Damit verhält sich Ordnung etwa zu *Ordnungsschrift* wie *Orden* ("Auszeichnung*) zu *Ordensabzeichen* usw., bzw. auch *Recht* zu *Rechtschreibung*, eigentlich zu *Reich*" realm", wie *Gesetz* zu *Satz*, *Schriftsatz*, während *Recht-* als Calque bei *Ortho-Graphie*, was weitgehend als richtig verstanden wird, aber auch im Sinne von *Festschrift* im Gegensatz zu *Kursiv, cura* verstanden werden dürfte.

Das ist anders als in der Frage gefordert doch ein Fremdwort. Ob es Lateinischen Ursprungs ist, sei dahingestellt. Zur Lösung sollte der angeführte Vergleich der Fragestellung gerecht werden, soweit dem in der Sprachwissenschaft eine Grundbedeutung *richtungsweisend* zugeschrieben wird: *zielgerichtete Prioritäten*—umschreibt den Ansatz zumindest grob. Für Übungsaufgaben reicht das allemal. Redundant ist *zielen* / *ausrichten* auch schon. Besser noch, insoweit *richten* ja auch die Aufrechterhaltung der Rechtsordnung zum Ziel hat, empfiehlt sich eine Anleihe aus juristischem Jargon: *angemessen*. Das wirkt wiederum unpassend, denn einerseits ist *Priorität* irgendwie auch Lateinsch. Selbst *messen* wäre zu leicht mit *Mensur* (vgl. *commensurate*) bzw. Altfranzösisch *mesure* zu verwechseln, doch vgl. *Messe* - Ordensritual, Wortherkunft dunkel. Sofern das Wort erst nach Errichtung deutsch-katholischer Staaten fußfast, dürfte es schon als deutsches Sprachgut gelten. Gleiches gilt übrigens für *Rang*; s. insb. "the non-officers of an army, taken as a group", vgl. *Ringer*, d.h. *Rangordnung* entspricht ungefähr Engl. *league*. An derer Seits passt *Vorliebe* so ausdruckstechnisch nicht hin. Es ist nicht klar, weshalb man angesichts *preferences* eher auf subjektivische *Vorlieben* wie Fetische abstellen sollte. Die Frage ist an der Stelle verfehlt. Eine reine Katastrophe.

In der Übersetzung könnte man bewusst versuchen, den kulturellen Kontext zu umschreiben. Falls dafür Grundannahmen gerechtfertigt sein müssen, ob etwa ein religiöser Hintergrund vorliegt, empfehlen sich weitere Nebensätze oder für längere Bemerkungen halt Fußnoten.

Comment: "messen", "-meter" und dgl. kommt vom altgriechischen "μέτρον" ("métron"), was soviel wie "Maß" oder "Länge" bedeutet, respektive dem Verb "metrein", was "messen" heißt. Das ist also ebenfalls eins der bösen Fremdwörter, die der O/P ersetzen wollte - ich frage mich nur, womit.

Comment: Auf derlei Problemchen in der Herleitung hatte ich bereits hingewiesen. Übrigens sehen das die geläufigen Wörterbücher anders, Althochdeutsch *mezzen* stamme mutmaßlich von urgermanisch \*metan ab, von einer urst gemeinsamen indo-europäischen Ursprache ab. Ist natürlich aales Quatsch mit Soße, brauch man sich nicht drüber zu streiten.